# Esse meu código está printando o vetor "forca" duas vezes não sei porque

Tags: c, array, loop, for

Esse código é de um jogo simples de forca, onde o vetor "forca" é printada.
Acho que tem algum problema na hora de imprimir esse vetor, pq sempre fica duplicado, mas não sei como resolver o problema.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char palavra[8], letra, tentativa[8];
    int i, j;
    int tent = 0;
    int corretas = 0;
    
    //armazena a palavra.
    for(i = 0; i <  8; i++){
        scanf("%c", &palavra[i]);
        tentativa[i] = '-';
    }

    while(tent < 10){
        scanf("%c", &letra);
        
        
        
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if(letra == palavra[j]){
                tentativa[j] = palavra[j];
                corretas = corretas + 1;
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            printf("%c", tentativa[i]);
        }printf("\n");
        
    }
    if(corretas==8){
        printf("Acertou!");
    }else if(tent >= 10){
        printf("Errou.");
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não existe "vetor forca" no exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

O `scanf` só está pegando um caractere. Então quando você digita uma letra "a" no console seguido de um espaço ou enter, a entrada fica `"a\n"` ou `"a "`. Então o `scanf` pega duas vezes. Uma para a letra que você digitou e a outra para o espaço em branco ou quebra de linha.

**Método 1:**

Substitua o tipo `%c` por `%s` que ele irá ler a string inteira, mas só irá salvar na variável o primeiro caractere, já que o tipo da variável é char.

```c
scanf("%s", &letra);
```

**Método 2:**

Se você sabe que sempre vai finalizar a entrada com uma quebra de linha(Apertando enter). Pode alterar o `scanf` para ler o conteúdo, mas excluir a quebra de linha da variável, adicionando um `\n`, logo após o `%c`.

```c
scanf("%c\n", &letra);
```